# Laravel: Getting the right IP behind Load Balanced AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-6

My Laravel 6.x setup consists of a Docker, running in an Elastic Beanstalk proxying with NGinx that is behind a load balancer.

With that setup, I'm having a real hard time to get the correct IP address, which is affecting the Throttle middleware, because the IP Laravel gets is either from the host machine or from the load balancer.

So, every user is in concurrence with everyone for the limits of the throttle.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

That's a copy of $_SERVER. The correct IP, in this case, is the first one in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. Correct IP for this scenario is `188.67.242.77`.

```
Array
(
    ...
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 172.31.28.165
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 188.67.242.77, 172.31.28.165
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT] => 443
    ... 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
    [SERVER_NAME] => {MASKED}
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 172.17.0.3
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 172.17.0.1
    ...
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 47334
    ...
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1584032941.764
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1584032941
)
```

Tested changing everything I could imagine in TrustProxies.php. `protected $headers` set to `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB`, `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL`, `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, and `protected $proxies` to `*` and `**`. Mixed and matched the possibilities. No good. I got either the 172.17.0.1 (host ip) or 172.31.28.165 (load balancer ip)

Any ideas?

Thank you so much in advance

=== UPDATE March 17th ===

The AWS proxy nginx file

```
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default        "upgrade";
        ""            "";
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        gzip on;
            gzip_comp_level 4;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass            http://docker;
            proxy_http_version    1.1;

            proxy_set_header    Connection            $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

=== Update March 18th ===

The apache vhost file inside Docker

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Laravel instance is running in a Docker container and is served by nginx, you can overwrite the `REMOTE_ADDR` with `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` in your Docker's nginx virtual host config.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.php index.html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/public_html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

        # Override the load balancer IP with real IP.
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome @mllnd. Thank you so much. I'll give it a shot next week.

Comment: no good. I updated the thread with the default AWS NGINX config. 

$http_x_real_ip seems empty in this context.

Comment: @AndréGumieri Could you also share your nginx vhost inside your Docker instance? The one that actually serves Laravel.

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear, but inside Docker is running Apache actually. vhost file is updated in the thread. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AndréGumieri in that case, I believe this article might help you - https://www.globo.tech/learning-center/x-forwarded-for-ip-apache-web-server/